# Tensorflow run on cluster (40k cores, 500TFLOP/s and 40k of RAM ) vs NVIDIA GTX 1080

Tags: python, tensorflow, cluster-computing, nvidia, slurm

I have the opportunity to run my Tensorflow training on a cluster computer with slurm workload manager (the cluster contains nearly 400000 cores, 40000 GB of RAM, Perfomance is Rmax=500 TFlop/s and Rpeak=1000 TFlop/s, AMD GPUs). The problem is that I will use the CPU version of Tensorflow, I don't know how to use AMD for training in Tensorflow.

I would like to how much faster is to run may training on this cluster (Tensorflow-CPU) versus running it on my laptop equipped with NVIDIA GTX 1080 (using Tensorlfow-GPU)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because system benchmarks are not a programming topic.

Comment: I respect your opinion, but this is related to programming directly not system benchmarking.

Comment: So, what code is it directly related to?

Comment: He/she is asking how to configure/program Tensorflow to pick up the AMD GPU stack.  Benchmarking the setup is not relevant to the question